# Timer with a Dimmer Switch

Tags: lighting, exterior, dimmer-switch, timer, multiway-switch

I have exterior lights on a timer switch.  The lights are too bright.  Can I add a dimmer switch to adjust the brightness?  And change the timer switch to a three-way switch.  Will that work?

Comment: Can you clarify how you want the switches to function?  Do you want the light to come on only if the timer tells it to come on, and another switch to control whether the timer can do that at all (basically serves to disable or not disable the timer), or the other switch overrides the timer and reverses whether the light is on or off?

Comment: The timer switch to tell when the lights should be on and off.  And a dimmer switch to control the brightness of the lights.  Unless both can be done in one switch.

Comment: If that's the intention and you can't find a combined timer/dimmer, have the timer feed the dimmer and the dimmer feed the light (wire the dimmer to the light; instead of feeding the dimmer directly from the power, feed it from the timer output that would normally go to the light, and feed the timer from the power).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add a dimmer switch to adjust the brightness?

Yes, the dimmer would just be added in series with the timer.

> And change the timer switch to a three-way switch

Normally, a timer controller goes on the feed to the circuit for outside lights without any other switches. However, you can wire things any way you have the imagination for within reason. If you connect the timer as a 3-way the other switch will override the timer anytime it is operated. If that is how you want the circuit to operate then it can be done.

A switch like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Honeywell-PLS750C1000-Ti072-3W-Sunrise-Required/dp/B01IAEPFD4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IAEPFD4)
Can be used as a single pole or 3-way switch.

Good luck and stay safe!